# How to send to my converter the binding object instead of specific property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

So this is my `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Count {get; set;}
   public bool IsChecked {get; set;}
}
```

This model is also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

`XAML`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="fileNameTextBlock"
           Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

So my question is in case i want to write `convertor` and send to it all my object `MyData` instead of sent this `Name` property how can i do that ?

Is it possible or in this case i need to use `IMultiValueConverter` instead of `IValueConverter` ?

Comment: you mention a multi-value converter, and errors on your attempt to just use {Binding}.  What are you trying to get to happen where you NEED a multi-value converter.  There may be other options available.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Property in Binding expression, just use

```
Text="{Binding}"
```

It will bind the DataContext (I suppose, it will be your model).

Comment: After this Binding i am add my converter so it expected another argument and not complie